# Get Javascript value from Dynamically adding/removing input fields in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

Im following this link [here](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery)

How can I get the values from all the text boxes into an array in my javascript form? I tried to nest it into a form; however, I can't get the HTML ID because it keeps changing when I add/remove a jQuery textbox field

Html

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selector `".input_fields_wrap input[name='mytext[]']"` to get all dynamic `<input>` elements having `name` attribute set to `"mytext[]"` passed to `document.querySelectorAll()` and `Array.from()` or alternatively `jQuery()` and `$.map()` to create array having same values

```js
let values = Array.from(
               document
               .querySelectorAll(".input_fields_wrap input[name='mytext[]']")
            , ({value}) => value);

console.log(values);
```

```html
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" value="0"></div>
</div>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" value="1"></div>
</div>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" value="2"></div>
</div>
```

```js
let values = $.map($(".input_fields_wrap input[name='mytext[]']")
            , ({value}) => value);

console.log(values);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" value="0"></div>
</div>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" value="1"></div>
</div>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" value="2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! how would this work on a node.js server?

Comment: How is node.js related to elements within an HTML document?

Answer (score 0):

Get your value based on name.

Example :

```
$('input[name^="mytext"]').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```